# Max function and group by getting differenet count

Tags: aggregate, database-agnostic

Statement 1 :

```
Select Load_Date , Count(*) Last_Count From <Table_Name> group by Load_Date;
```

Statement 2 :

```
Select max(Load_Date) , Count(*) Last_Count From <TABLE_NAME>;
```

Statement 1 `max Date count` is different and statement 2 `max date count` is different.

I need your help to understand the output.

Answer (score 1):

The first query returns the count of rows across a given load_date.
Whereas the second query gives you the count of rows for maximum load_date.
Say you have 2 dates. First query returns :

```
LoadDate.           Count(*)
03-04-2014.          12
03-05-2014.           11
```

Second query returns:

```
Max(loadDate).      Count(*)
03-05-2014.             23
```

If you want that the count of just max row be found, then the query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM <table name>
WHERE LoadDate = MAX(loadDate);
```